# Permission denied (publickey) Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote when running cap production deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh, capistrano3

I have tried to redeploy an old Rail project. Yersterday I encounter the permission denied(public key) problem, but it is solved after i reconfigured ssh of git based on https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/.

However, today I tried to redeploy it again, the same problem pops up, and even after I reconfigured the ssh of git.

```
gdacs@hostname:/home/deploy/xxxx/current$ cap local deploy
DEBUG [6908bd83] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2 ] as deploy@hostname
DEBUG [6908bd83] Command: [ -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2 ]
deploy@hostname's password:
DEBUG [6908bd83] Finished in 5.858 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [b8d56ba2] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/xxxx/ as deploy@hostname
DEBUG [b8d56ba2] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 /usr/bin/env                                                                                                                                                              mkdir -p /tmp/xxxx/ )
INFO [b8d56ba2] Finished in 0.111 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/xxxx/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
INFO Uploading /tmp/xxxx/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
INFO [92d9f56c] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/xxxx/git-ssh.sh as de                                                                                                                                                             ploy@hostname
DEBUG [92d9f56c] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 /usr/bin/env                                                                                                                                                              chmod +x /tmp/xxxx/git-ssh.sh )
INFO [92d9f56c] Finished in 0.136 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [1410940c] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@github.com:xxxx.git as deploy@hostname
DEBUG [1410940c] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 GIT_ASKPASS=                                                                                                                                                             /bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/xxxx/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@gi                                                                                                                                                             thub.com:xxxx.git )
DEBUG [1410940c]        Error reading response length from authentication socket                                                                                                                                                             .
DEBUG [1410940c]        Permission denied (publickey).
DEBUG [1410940c]        fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
DEBUG [1410940c]
DEBUG [1410940c]        Please make sure you have the correct access rights
DEBUG [1410940c]        and the repository exists.
DEBUG [1410940c] Finished in 0.891 seconds with exit status 128 (failed).
cap aborted!
Exception while executing as deploy@hostname: exit

 Tasks: TOP => git:check
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception w                                                                                                                                                             hile executing as deploy@hostname: exit>
```

Afterwards, I also checked the publickey authorization of my git account:

```
gdacs@hostname:/home/deploy/xxxx/current$ ssh -T git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' to the list of known hosts.
Hi xxxxxx! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Anybody has idea what went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: you have your ssh keys in `gdacs` account, but not on `deploy` account?

Comment: do you have the user name deploy with all the permissions....?add the user to the admin group with sudo privileges

Comment: @MangooSaSa: will you tell me how you solved your issue coz I'm also on same page ?